# How can I show the current time with xamarin.forms, DateTime.Now not updating in real time on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

DateTime.Now does not update the hour minutes and seconds in real time when the application is opened in android, what are my options?. also as it could capture the month, day, year, hour and minutes, you could show me your examples.

Comment: You have to use a timer.  Xamarin has several sample apps that show how to build your own clock.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?terms=clock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a ViewModel and bind it with label or something else.

ViewModel is like:

```
    class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        DateTime dateTime;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ClockViewModel()
        {
            this.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                {
                    this.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    return true;
                });
        }

        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            set
            {
                if (dateTime != value)
                {
                    dateTime = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateTime"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return dateTime;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is xaml:

```
    <Label Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat='{0:T}'}"
           FontSize="Large"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label.BindingContext>
            <local:ClockViewModel />
        </Label.BindingContext>
    </Label>
</ContentPage>
```